# array_flip with an array in the value

Tags: php, arrays, array-flip

Simple one (but not solved yet): this is my array

```
[
 [
   "role" => "admin",
   "name" => [
     "Felipy",
     "Ivan",
   ],
 ],
 [
   "role" => "user",
   "name" => [
     "Michel",
     "Paul",
     "Tay",
 ],
]
```

And I would love to see this result:

```
[
 "Felipy" => "admin",
 "Ivan" => "admin",
 "Michael" => "user",
 "Paul" => "user",
 "Tay" => "user",
]
```

I've already tried [`array_flip`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-flip.php)

Comment: Try something else)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
foreach ($yourArr as $role) {
 foreach ($role['name'] as $user) {
    $arr[$user] = $role['role'];
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try this [DEMO](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/33c43c8ae990ac9cd2e25e1f8971f6afcf4f6d43)

```
$original = [
     [
       "role" => "admin",
       "name" => [
         "Felipy",
         "Ivan",
       ],
     ],
     [
       "role" => "user",
       "name" => [
         "Michel",
         "Paul",
         "Tay",
        ],
      ]
    ];
    $arr = [];

    foreach ($original as $value)
    {
       foreach($value['name'] as $name)
       {
           $arr[$name] = $value['role'];
       }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this [Live demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/82414841b30f1468ee23d0c7543921429ac16628)

```
$array = [
 [
   "role" => "admin",
   "name" => [
     "Felipy",
     "Ivan",
   ]
 ],
 [
   "role" => "user",
   "name" => [
      "Michel",
      "Paul",
      "Tay"
   ]
 ]
];

$result = array_reduce($array, function($carry, $key) {
    foreach ($key['name'] as $name)
        $carry[$name] = $key['role'];
    return $carry;
}, []);

var_dump($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Less clear but still working solution:

```
$a = [
 [
   "role" => "admin",
   "name" => [
     "Felipy",
     "Ivan",
   ],
 ],
 [
   "role" => "user",
   "name" => [
     "Michel",
     "Paul",
     "Tay",
    ],
 ],
];

$r = [];
foreach ($a as $item) {
    $r = array_merge($r, array_fill_keys($item['name'], $item['role']));
}
echo'<pre>',print_r($r),'</pre>';
```

Comment: Didn't knew this `array_fill_keys` method! Thanks!